# How to show a checkmark with username?

Tags: 7, users

I want to show a checkmark besides a username for verified accounts. Users who belong to a certain user role will be assigned this checkmark. I know about the [userbadge](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_badges) module, but do not know whether it is the right choice. If I had to give an example, I would say like twitter shows a check sign with verified users.

Comment: Are you saying that ANYWHERE this user's name is listed on the site, that you'd like a checkmark next to it? If so, and you're comfortable with code, the hook_username_alter() hook would be a good start.

Comment: @UnsettlingTrend I do not know how to code. I want to show the check sign with only a particular role. For example: There are 3 types of user roles. Administrator, Authenticated and Privileged. So I only want to show check sign with users belonging to "Privileged" user role. And Yes, anywhere the username is listed.